# Trouble understanding fseek offset

Tags: c, stdio

I have a text file, where each line is an integer with a newline character. I also have a .bin file with the same thing.

```
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
```

Running this code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int input;
    FILE *infile_t = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    FILE *infile_b = fopen("numbers.bin", "rb");

    if (infile_t == NULL) {
            printf("Error: unable to open file %s\n", "numbers.txt");
            exit(1);
    }

    if (infile_b == NULL) {
            printf("Error: unable to open file %s\n", "numbers.bin");
            exit(1);
    }

    printf("Enter an integer index: ");
    while(scanf("%d",&input) != EOF){
        int ch;

        fseek(infile_t, (input*sizeof(int))-1, SEEK_SET);
        fscanf(infile_t, "In text file: %d\n", &ch);
        printf("In text file: %d\n", ch);

        fseek(infile_b, (input*sizeof(int))-1, SEEK_SET);
        fscanf(infile_b, "%d\n", &ch);
        printf("In binary file: %d\n", ch);

        printf("Enter an integer index: ");
    }

    fclose(infile_t);
    fclose(infile_b);

    return 0;
}
```

and entering 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 consecutively, I get the outputs:
10
0
40
50
0

I am trying to read the file by 4 bytes at a time (each int) and print the integer. What am I doing wrong and if this is bad practice, what would be better?

Comment: "_4 bytes at a time (each int)_" - Each `int` takes up 2 bytes + 1 or 2 bytes for `\n` or `\r\n` in the text file you show

Comment: What is `numbers.bin` ? Is it the text file you show in the question?

Comment: Why `4` in `input*4`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Obviously, `numbers.bin` is the example file. And if the file has been created under Windows, a line break is two bytes long, so each line is 2 characters + 2 bytes line break.

Comment: I just tested your program under Ubuntu (using DOS line endings in `numbers.bin`): It works fine. In other programs, I made the experience that `FILE *fopen()`-type files (unlike `int open()`-type files) sometimes make problems with `fseek()`. As a workaround, I used an `fflush()` before and after the `fseek()`: `fflush(f); fseek(f,...); fflush(f);`

Comment: Thank you to all who have helped. I have updated the code. I believe I was reading byte 1 in the 4 byte integers in the bin file. I get the expected outcome now for the bin file, but not the text file. I am assuming I should format the text file in some different way? I'm having trouble figuring that out. The numbers in the txt and bin file are the same and can be any numbers. They are written to each file by a different program.

Comment: update: Nevermind, not working as intended will keep working on.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between the textual representation of numbers and their binary representation.

Your input is a text file, which is a sequence of characters:

"10`lf`20`lf`30`lf`40`lf`50`lf`60`lf`70`lf`"

Its size is 21 bytes, which you could check with your file explorer.

And as bytes in a tabular form it looks like this, assumed that you are using ASCII and a unix-like system:

| Offset | Bytes | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 31 30 0A | "10`lf`" |
| 3 | 32 30 0A | "20`lf`" |
| 6 | 33 30 0A | "30`lf`" |
| 9 | 34 30 0A | "40`lf`" |
| 12 | 35 30 0A | "50`lf`" |
| 15 | 36 30 0A | "60`lf`" |
| 18 | 37 30 0A | "70`lf`" |

There are no integers stored in binary form in your input file.

The function `fseek()` places the "cursor" into the file at the specified offset.

Then you call `scanf()` to scan and interpret(!) the sequence of characters that start at that offset.

| Input | Offset set by `fseek()` | Text | Resulting value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | "10`lf`..." | 10 |
| 1 | 4 | "0`lf`..." | 0 |
| 2 | 8 | "`lf`40`lf`..." | 40 |
| 3 | 12 | "50`lf`..." | 50 |
| 4 | 16 | "0`lf`..." | 0 |

Since `scanf()` skips leading whitespace, you get "40" in the third case.

You cannot use `fseek()` in the general case to "jump" to a certain line in a text file. Except, that you **know** how long each line is. In your case this is known, and if you use a factor of 3 instead of 4, you will get what you seem to want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is in your 'numbers.bin', and you opened 'numbers.txt' as infile_t but didn't use it.

Assuming that the content in 'numbers.bin' is the text content in your question, and you open it in binary mode for reading, the contents stored in the file are as follows(end with one byte '\n' instead of two bytes '\r\n'):

`\x31\x30\x0a\x32\x30\x0a\x33\x30\x0a\x34\x30\x0a\x35\x30\x0a\x36\x30\x0a\x37\x30`

At this time, the file pointer is at the head of the file, pointing to the text content '1'(ascii code is 0x31).

```
\x31\x30\x0a\x32\x30\x0a\x33\x30\x0a\x34\x30\x0a\x35\x30\x0a\x36\x30\x0a\x37\x30
↑
```

when you use `scanf("%d",&input)` and input '0', the integer variable `input` will be 0, then you set the file pointer via `fseek(infile_b, input*4, SEEK_SET)`, the file pointer will point to offset 0 relative to the beginning of the file.

Next line `fscanf(infile_b, "%d\n", &ch)` will read a integer value to variable `ch`, then `ch` will store the value 10 and print it to standard output (`stdout`) via printf.

When you enter '1', the file pointer will be set to 4, which will point to the fifth byte position relative to the beginning of the file, as follows:

```
\x31\x30\x0a\x32\x30\x0a\x33\x30\x0a\x34\x30\x0a\x35\x30\x0a\x36\x30\x0a\x37\x30
                ↑
```

The ascii code of the text value '0' is 0x30. It will read an integer value 0 and store it in `ch`.

You can replace `fseek(infile_b, input*4, SEEK_SET)` with `fseek(infile_b, input*3, SEEK_SET)`, and will get the expected output.